# Unable to split a tuple object in Python: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, sockets, split, tuples

When I try to run my program I get the error shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Volumes/USER/server.py", line 15, in <module>
filename = message.split()[1]
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I tried changing the value for
filename = message.split()[0] but it didn't work.

```
#import socket module
import socket 
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
#Prepare a sever socket 
serverName = socket.gethostname()
serverPort = 1234
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
while True:     
#Establish the connection    
    print('Ready to serve...')     
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    try:         
        message =  connectionSocket.recvfrom(1024)
        filename = message.split()[1]
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = f.read()
        #Send one HTTP header line into socket         
        header = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n' +\
            'Connection: close\r\n' + \
            'Content-Type: text/html\r\n' + \
            'Content-Length: %d\r\n\r\n' % (len(outputdata))
        connectionSocket.send(header.encode())
        #Send the content of the requested file to the client
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())
        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        #Send response message for file not found
        header = 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n'
        connectionSocket.send(header.encode())
        #Close client socket
        connectionSocket.close()
serverSocket.close()
```

In the same directory as the program, server.py, I have a file called helloworld.html thats supposed to load when I go to the IP address of the server with the hard coded port and also show a 404 when I go to a file that doesn't exist. ex (192.168.1.2:1234/helloworld.html)

Comment: `recvfrom()` returns a tuple and a tuple doesn't understand `split()`.

Answer (score 0):

[Per the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html):

> **`socket.accept()`**
>
> > Accept a connection. The socket must be bound to an address and listening for connections. The return value is a pair `(conn, address)` where conn is a new socket object usable to send and receive data on the connection, and address is the address bound to the socket on the other end of the connection.

So, in your code, after you do

```
message =  connectionSocket.recvfrom(1024)
filename = message.split()
```

`message` becomes a tuple `(conn, address)`.

Now, tuples don't have the method `split()`. Only strings have that method. What I think you're trying to do is split the *address* - so you have to first get the second element of the tuple (which is, of course, a string), and then split *that*:

```
filename = message[1].split()
```